# New .NET feature bundle and minification {version} wildcard doesn't work with directories?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, asp.net-optimization

I have the following pice of code which runs perfectly:

```
bundles.Add
(
    new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts")
    .Include
    (
        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"
        ,"~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"
        ,"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"
        ,"~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"
        ,"~/Scripts/fullcalendar-1.5.4/fullcalendar.js"
        , "~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.3/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
    )
);
```

But then I want to use the {version} wildcard to use all of it's nifty features:

```
bundles.Add
(
    new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts")
    .Include
    (
        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"
        ,"~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"
        ,"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"
        ,"~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"
        , "~/Scripts/fullcalendar-{version}/fullcalendar.js"
        , "~/Scripts/DataTables-{version}/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
    )
);
```

and BANG, exception, it doesn't work, am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

***Exception info:***
System.ArgumentException:

Directory does not exist.
Parameter name: directoryVirtualPath

***Stack:***

> [ArgumentException: Directory does not exist. Имя параметра:
>   directoryVirtualPath]
>   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.Include(String[] virtualPaths) +40
>   Aerostar.BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) in
>   c:\Users\Denis\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\Aerostar\Aerostar\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs:21
>   Aerostar.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in
>   c:\Users\Denis\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\Aerostar\Aerostar\Global.asax.cs:24
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Directory does not exist. Имя параметра:
>   directoryVirtualPath]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +9859725
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +336
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Directory does not exist. Имя параметра:
>   directoryVirtualPath]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9873912 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

Comment: It'll might be helpful for anyone reading this to know *what* exception. =)

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That is correct, currently the {version} expression is only supported as part of the file, its not used while doing directory walking.  This is something that we will look into fixing in a future version.

I filed an issue for [this here on codeplex](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/29).

Please vote it up if this is something you feel strongly about us fixing.